# How to change hash password validation into normal password?

Tags: php, authentication, hash

I am setting up a new website with registration and login forms. As a beginner I am usting mostly part of codes I find online and in books. I have finished registration form and it works perfectly, but now I have a problem with a login form, because all codes that I can find are based on hashed password and the login form I have to build does not need it. Can you help to convert the script I have now into script that will work without any password (instead of a password it just need a 6 digital number which is not hashed).

I tried check_login, but it did not work.

```
     $sql = "SELECT id, email, pin FROM users WHERE email = ?";

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_email);

        // Set parameters
        $param_email = $email;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if($stmt->execute()){
            // Store result
            $stmt->store_result();

            // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
            if($stmt->num_rows == 1){                    
                // Bind result variables
                $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $numerpin);
                if($stmt->fetch()){
                   if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
                        // Password is correct, so start a new session
                        session_start();

                        // Store data in session variables
                        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                        $_SESSION["email"] = $email;                            

                        // Redirect user to welcome page
                        header("location: dashboard.php");
                    } else{
                        // Display an error message if password is not valid
                        $numerpin_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                    }
                }
            } else{
                // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                $email_err = "No account found with that username.";
            }
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever to store passwords as plain text instead of using some kind of encryption. However, if you really want to do that, you can achieve that removing this `if` statement which uses `password_verify` to check if the password matches a hash. I think it should solve the problem - at least, is what I can assume based exclusively on this small portion of code you showed to us...

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment! I added more of the code. To log in an user has to provide e-mail and password, but not a hashed one. I think if I remove if statement I will be able to log in only with an e-mail, right?

Comment: I think you misunderstood a basic thing. The user provides a clear password. you hash that, and compare it to the stored hash `if hash(user_provided_cleartext_pw) == stored_hash` then user is correct

Comment: The user does not provide a password. The form I have built generates a 6 digital code for them and then they use their e-mail and the generated code to log in and an admin of the page must see the 6 digital code, so I do not hash anything. 

I assume the first part of the code is correct (e-mail validation), but I do not how to make the form check if an e-mail and 6 digital code are correct together!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this query:

```
"SELECT id, email, pin FROM users WHERE email = ?"
```

You are checking for the email to be correct. You could change it to

```
"SELECT id, email, pin FROM users WHERE email = ? and pin = ?"
```

of course, passing pin as well. Also, your error message is misleading:

```
               if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
                    // Password is correct, so start a new session
                    session_start();

                    // Store data in session variables
                    $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                    $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                    $_SESSION["email"] = $email;                            

                    // Redirect user to welcome page
                    header("location: dashboard.php");
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if password is not valid
                    $numerpin_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                }
```

what if there are multiple records with the very same email? In that case it will say that password is incorrect, without checking its actual value. It would be much more reliable to get the record(s) by email and pin, loop the results and when a match is found, then create a session. If there is no match, then error.

Comment: Thank you so much! Using your tips let me fix my code and learn something new! :D

Comment: @JasonWysocki you are welcome, I'm glad that the problem you have experienced is solved.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested. The best approach is to use hash password but since you do not want that. you can go ahead with this. Try the code below

```
    <?php
           $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'your username', 'your password', 'your db name');
      if($mysqli->connect_error){
        echo "cannot connect to database";
      }

    // assuming your post variable is set as follows
          $email = $_POST['email'];
          $pin = $_POST['pin'];

          $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, email, pin FROM users WHERE email = ? AND pin = ?");

/* i is for integer and s is for string. I suspect that your pin must be integer so I set the bind to i
*/

          $stmt->bind_param("si", $email, $pin);
          if($stmt->execute()){
            $stmt->store_result();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
          }
          if($num_rows == 1){

     // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["email"] = $email;                            

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: dashboard.php");


          }else{
            echo "Error: Either Email or Pin number is wrong";
          }
        ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Using your and Lajos Arpad's answers let me fix my code. :D